# Response redirect in Connect

Tags: node.js, connect, response.redirect

In Express, Im able to redirect to other url using response.redirect(""). Similarly how can I redirect in Connect module? I've tried the below code but its not working.

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
response.end('<p>302. Redirecting to <a href="' + url+ '">' + url+ '</a></p>');
```

Comment: setting the `Location` header is one option. haven't explored the connect api thought, i should be similar to express

Answer (score 6):

You can also redirect in Connect using `writeHead` as follows:

```
res.writeHead(301, {Location: url});
res.end();
```

The 301 http status code means "moved permanently".

Comment: I tried doing this but Im getting request headers as CAUTION:Provisional headers are shown

Comment: Is there any way to pass data along with the redirect url?

Comment: You can pass query string parameters in the url if that might work in your case. I have not needed to pass post data in a redirect before.

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect` is defined in express, not in connect (see the [relevant source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.4.8/lib/response.js#L682)). You then can't use this function, but you can copy its behavior by setting the `Location` header:

```
res.set('Location', url);
```

You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/2137601): even if is related to [php](/questions/tagged/php), it contains useful information regarding the use of the header.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles across this, `res.set` is now `res.setHeader`