# How to make redirect from www to non-www in nuxt.js

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Who knows how to make redirects in nuxt.js from www to non-www?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate.
for redirection, you have `nuxt-link` or anchor tag with href or router push

Comment: @HardikShah,  I have a project on nuxt.js (universal mode) and I want to make redirect each time when user open link with www for example (www.example.com) to non-www url (example.com)

Answer (score 1):

Incase any is still having this issue.

I had to solve it with CloudFlare using this article
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-

You can also achieve it with serverMiddleware
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-server-middleware

Create a file and paste in the following code.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const host = req.headers.host
  const url = req.url
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
  const forceDomain = 'https://masteringbackend.com'

  if (env === 'production' && host !== 'www.masteringbackend.com') {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: forceDomain + url })
    return res.end()
  }

  return next()
}
```

Then you register the file in `serverMiddleware`

Another way

You can take a look at https://mindthecode.com/blog/how-to-redirect-www-traffic-to-non-www-in-your-express-app/ but remember that res.redirect is only for Express, to do redirect in Connect (pure node.js http): [Response redirect in Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141137/response-redirect-in-connect)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding Kaperskyguru shared code for the serverMiddleware: It is almost perfect, but the "if line" should be "===" instead of "!==". For me this one works:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
 const host = req.headers.host
 const url = req.url
 const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
 const forceDomain = 'https://masteringbackend.com'

 if (env === 'production' && host === 'www.masteringbackend.com') {
   res.writeHead(301, { Location: forceDomain + url })
   return res.end()
 }

 return next()
}
```